# adding values of the same keys in dictionary inside a loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I just import a csv file and convert it to a dictionary and also assigned field name for the different columns. Can someone teach me how to add the value of the same keys in this dictionary in loop?

```
import csv


with open("breast_cancer_v1.csv", newline='') as file:


    fieldnames = ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']

    print ("1:  ID", "\n2:  Diagnosis", "\n3:  a) radius (mean of distances from center to points on the perimeter)", "\n4:  b) texture (standard deviation of gray-scale values)", "\n5:  c) perimeter", "\n6:  d) area", "\n7:  e) smoothness (local variation in radius lengths)", "\n8:  f) compactness (perimeter^2 / area - 1.0)", "\n9:  g) concavity (severity of concave portions of the contour)", "\n10: h) concave points (number of concave portions of the contour)", "\n11: i) symmetry", "\n12: j) fractal dimension (coastline approximation - 1)")

    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames)

    for row in csv_file:

        print(row)
```

[image]

example: i wan to add all the values in column "3" or count how many "B" in column "2". Still learning how to access the dictionary. i managed to print out my dictionary in the loop after importing the csv and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: access column 3 as `row['3']` and for column 2 use `row['2']`

Comment: If this is not for how to juggle around with dictionaries learning purposes, you should definitely have a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), its [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#dataframe) and in this case the [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) importer function...